# Stuck to create Paypal App Id to integrate with iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I am trying to develop iPhone shopping application. In my app, I integrate with Paypay checkout payment. It request "Paypal App ID".

When I try to create "Paypal App ID" in http://www.x.com (login with Paypal account and go to "My Account" and then "New App" ). It request "Testing Information", I have to show "Step-by-Step Payment Flows Instructions" for reviewing by them.

But I did not upload my iPhone app to Apple store yet, I can not show them the demo.
They also do not provide UDID of their iphone/ipad to allow me deploy Ah Hoc Distribution to show them.

What I have to do to pass this step, to allow me get "Paypal App ID"?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried with Sanbox already, and now I want to update to LIVE environment.